# Add local font to wordpress create-block plugin

Tags: wordpress, font-face, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am trying to complete the https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/handbook/tutorials/create-block/block-code/ tutorial.

I did what they say but the font only works on the backend. I didn't add any wp-enqueues, just the code mentioned there. I tried with a second font - just in case - but the result is the same.
The frontend gives a 404 as the style is added in the page inlined. That is:

```
    <style id='create-block-gutenpride-style-inline-css'>
        @font-face {
            font-family: Gilbert;
            src: url(fonts/gilbert-color.02d3d364.otf);
            font-weight: bold
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: AmaticSC;
            src: url(fonts/AmaticSC-Regular.caaf513a.ttf)
        }

        .wp-block-create-block-gutenpride {
            font-family: AmaticSC;
            font-size: 64px
        }
    </style>
```

I tried using both fonts and they produce the same error. The files exist on the generated *fonts* folder but the src is a 404: `http://gutenberg-dev.local/fonts/AmaticSC-Regular.caaf513a.ttf`

Everything is working properly on the block editor as the CSS file is enqueued and the relative URLs work.

Have you found a solution for this?
How can we make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how this is supposed to be done, but try an absolute path to the file.

If the path to your file is https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/gilbert-color.otf then try adding this to the /src/style.scss file in your plugin:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Gilbert;
    src: url(https://mywebsite/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/gilbert-color.otf);
    font-weight: bold;
}
.my-namespace-my-block {
    font-family: Gilbert;
    font-size: 64px;
}
```

Then run

```
npm run build
```

Reload the post and refresh the browser and check the published page.

This works for me, though I may be missing something. The tutorial is pretty vague. https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/create-block/block-code/

Comment: thank you @NIck, this might work for a certain website but it's not usable when you use it on a plugin

Comment: By the way, I think the latest WordPress versions inline some small files in the `<head>` making relative paths useless

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using a font from a CDN like google fonts. Import it to the front and backend. Not exactly what the tutorial suggests, but it saved me a load of time trying to do something the tutorial isn't about.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'rubik-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik+Beastly&display=swap' );
});

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'rubik-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik+Beastly&display=swap' );
});
```